# In XSD, what's the meaning/purpose of a simpleType/restriction/simpleType element?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, restriction

In an XML Schema Definition (XSD) document, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256057.aspx), one can have a **simpleType** element containing a **restriction** element that may have another **simpleType** element.

I have browsed many **restriction** / **simpleType** related pages including the W3 Schema Primer, yet I have not been able to find a simple explanation of how this should be interpreted by an XSD processor. I get what a simpleType is, I get most of its possible restrictions, but I can't quite figure out what a simpleType/restriction/simpleType construction is supposed to mean. How is this commonly / typically used by schema designers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an alternative to `base=""`.  Similar to an `<element>` having either `type=""` or a  `<complexType>` (but not both nor neither).

> {base type definition}    The Simple Type Definition component resolved to by the actual value of the `base`   [attribute] or the `<simpleType>`  [children], whichever is present.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#derivation-by-restriction

Answer (score 2):

XSD generally allows one definition to refer to another either by name (ref=NNNN), or by embedding the other definition inline. I can't see any strong reason use this mechanism for defining the base type of a type derived by restriction, but it's there for generality and consistency. (And just because I can't see a use for it doesn't mean there isn't one...)